# getting error while trying to use scala extractors without case classes

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and just learning to code . can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here

```
          class ForExtractor(val i : Int , j:Int){
    //def unapply(i:Int) = true
  }
  object ForExtractor{
    def unapply(i:Int ):Option[(Int , Int)] = if(i>2)Some(1,2) else None
  }
  def extractorTest(obj : ForExtractor) = {
    obj match {
      case ForExtractor(4,2)=> true ;
      case e => false
    }
  }
```

The error that i see on case line is

```
    pattern type is incompatible with expected type ; found:Int ,
    ForExtractor
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i can guess is that you want to test whether the `val i`
in your ForExtractor is bigger that 2 or not, and in this case return Some((1,2)) (notice your error here you're returning `Some(1,2)`).

your unapply method should take as argument a ForExtractor, so in the end the unapply method would look like this:

```
 def unapply(forex: ForExtractor):Option[(Int , Int)] = 
         if(forex.i > 2)Some((1,2)) else None
```

then we get:

```
scala> extractorTest(new ForExtractor(1, 2))
res1: Boolean = false
```